# Maximum load when placing N balls in N bins

Tags: probability

In an academic paper I am reading the following..

When $n$ balls are placed into $n$ bins (each ball being placed into a bin chosen
independently and uniformly at random) with high probability, the maximum load
in any bin is roughly $\log n/\log \log n$.

Can anyone explain how this is derived ? This is not a home work question; I just trying to figure out how this was worked out.

Comment: Not a simple problem. Some refs: http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2347220?uid=3737512&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21104800299091 http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.4373

Answer (score 2):

Here is a handwavy argument: the number of balls in a bin follows a Poisson distribution with $\lambda=1$ because the average number of balls/bin is $1$.  The probability that a given bin has $k$ balls is then $\frac {e^{-1}}{k!}$  The bin with maximum balls will have about $k$ balls when this probability is about $\frac 1n$, so we say (using Sterling) $$\frac {e^{-1}}{k!}=\frac 1n\\k!=\frac ne=\frac {k^k}{e^k}\sqrt{2 \pi k}\\\log n-1=k(\log k-1)+\frac 12 \log (2 \pi k)$$  For $n$ very large, the constants don't matter and the first approximation is $k=\log n$.  If we do a fixed point iteration, the next approximation  is $$\log n=k \log \log n\\k=\frac {\log n}{\log \log n}$$

Comment: I have some difficulty with the first approximation. Omitting all constants leads to $log( n) = k*log( k)$. To conclude from this that $k = log( n)$, seems hardly justified. It is more an order of magnitude estimation.

Comment: @M.Wind:  When $n$ is very large, $\log n \gg 1$ and all the constants are about $1$, so I think it is better than order of magnitude.  I would keep going in the fixed point vein if I wanted a better asymptotic.  To first order we are saying $log k \ll k$ and that $\log$ is slowly varying.

Comment: Thank you. I understand your reasoning. Still, for $log(n) >> 1$ to be valid implies that $n$ itself is an extremely large number, say 1 googol. I find this peculiar. It seems to me that in a problem like this, the "large $n$" behaviour occurs much sooner, say in the range 100 to 1000,000.

Comment: I agree with you that $log(k)$ is slowly varying compared to $k$. This would lead to me approximate $log(k)$ in the region of interest by a constant, say $C$. This would result in: $k = (1/C)*log(n)$. If we substitute this result back in our equation, we get approximately $C = log(log(n))$. The same result as you got, but without the requirement $log(n) >> 1$.

Comment: Please note that your third RHS is not quite right. (Although this  does not affect your further calculation.)

Comment: @M.Wind:  Thanks.  fixed

Comment: First two terms should be: $(k + 1/2)*log(k) - k$.